# Mobile frontend has a bug: container is not fixed

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, frontend

I suck at mobile frontend / responsiveness. Could someone tell me why the overall container of my webapp is not fixed but slides around when you move it?

I hope you get my question but you can basically move the whole page front left to right.

here ist the page: www.frankfurtstartupjobs.com

I am sure it is something simple, as of again I suck at mobile / css.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hmmm, I'd recommend you not to use negative margins. You have a lot of margins and paddings on almost every element and it's really messed up, the easiest workaround is to set overflow: hidden on the `.row` with the list of vacancies but the actual fix would be to simplify the margins and paddings (usually, if you have a padding on a parent and negative margins on it's children, that's a bad smell). Also the the `figure` element with the quote, the margin is also out of place. If you simplify the margins/paddings the issue will be gone.

Comment: Okay, the "overflow: hidden" trick on the .row did not work. I agree that the overall css policy is very messy. Major learning for the upcoming work. I was wondering if there was a simple fix to this. As otherwise I will have to review every single element..

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about page is moving around when we drag it then here is solution

[image]

look for class `container_header` in your html page and add `container` class to it

this will fix your issue

Comment: I did try this. Unfortunately it still moves around when being dragged.